# Hide excel on invoking chart.chartdata.activate() method

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word

I am trying to update chart data of an existing chart by using the following code snippet.

```
chart.ChartData.Activate();
workBook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)chart.Chart Data.Workbook;
workBook.Application.Visible = false; // hide GUI
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = workBook.Sheets[1];
```

The problem is that `.Activate();` causes a new instance of excel(with GUI) to appear. By using `workBook.Application.Visible = false;` am able to hide the GUI thereafter. So basically we have a pop-up effect of excel here i.e excel displays and disappears in a matter of "seconds". I do not want to see the excel GUI. How can I eliminate this effect. Is there probably a workaround?

Or is there a way of editing an existing chart(i.e .interop.word.chart) in a word document without excel being opened?

Comment: Hey FrankerZ. Which Office Version are you using? In my experience the way Excel is opened depends on the Office Version. Office 2010 seems to be more flickering than 2013 and 2016. Apart from that, I think that there is no other way of editing existing charts than the one you mention. Cheers. Jens

Comment: @Jens.Huehn_at_SlideFab.com Thanks for the reply. I have office 2010. Have not tried on other versions. Seems like a good pointer though.

Comment: It's not possible to edit a chart inside a Word document, using the interop, without Excel popping up. It can be done on the *closed* file by leveraging the Open XML file format.